# Magento - remove all special prices

Tags: magento

I need to remove all special prices in my magento stores and I can't understand a thing about magento's database structure when I look into phpMyAdmin.

Can someone guide me?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways of resolving this:

1) Look more at the Magento database, It uses several tables to map prices etc. As well as a single flat table if you have that enabled. To update all prices you need to look for the special price value in the varchar table, Take that ID and update its parent.

2) Create a PHP script that will load all products and loop through and update the values you want. Basic code would be:

```
// inside a loop
$product->setSpecialPrice(0);
$product->save();
```

An easy way to debug what SQL you need is to enable MySQL logging, Save a product and see what tables are being wrote to. Or even in the product catalog save event add an echo to the Entity after save to print out the generated SQL.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai  Obvious, thou geniusness is obvious.

Comment: In magento 2.1 the special price set to 0 which means free product?

Comment: If I am not wrong, even in Magento 1, $product->setSpecialPrice(0) will set the special price to $0, i.e. free. I've always used $product->setSpecialPrice('') instead.

Comment: I can confirm that in Magento 1.9.2.4, using $product->setSpecialPrice(0) will set the price to 0.00 (free). Using an empty string or null will clear the price.

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy way around to remove all the special prices from all products. You don't actually need to run any script. Just go to the `administration -> catalog -> manage products` and click on `select all` at the top left of the grid view. Then, in `actions` dropdown on the top-right, select `Update Attributes` and press `Submit`.

See the screenshot below:

[image: screen 1]

Now, in the Update Attribute Screen, scroll down to `Special Price` field, and check the `Change` checkbox. DO NOT put anything in the text box. Click on save.

See the screenshot below.

[image: screen 2]

It might take a while if you have many products, but it will work without disturbing your database. Once done, go to Index Management and Re-index everything.

Comment: Thanks this changed my life. I never realized that there is mass product update option. However limited it may be. I am having problems uploading the CSV. Even though I exported the product list and then added the simple products by duplicating the row above it. (Kept the image column with he same link as the image was the same, these were child products with different configuration for a configuratble product)  after upload it showed in frontend but product page in backend was stuck on loading. I had an open product tab editing it saving it worked but going back 2 product page gave same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove special price then create csv file for import and add blank valspecial price field using SKU and import that csv. Its remove all special prices.

Comment: I know this is not related But since you mentioned this I thought let me ask you directly instead of searching the internet for this. Cause this will not be mentioned directly anywhere.
The Question is. Can I just change any field through CSV.
Do I have to export/import all the columns. Or can I just upload a CSV with SKU column and then the required column next to it Like Price Or Description.
Does the upload work this way too? I tried uploading just 2 products by exporting it and then duplicating the row below with changes. After upload my product page in backend was not stuck on loading

Answer (score 1):

Direct from database.

Before execute bellow query export and keep backup "catalog_product_entity_decimal" table.

execute bellow query.

> DELETE from  `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where attribute_id in (
>   select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code =
>   'special_price');

Answer (score 0):

You can just select fields blank and save changes then all special prices will be remove.
[image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSTFV.png)

Answer (score -3):

The Question is why you need to remove them? You could also hide them using CSS, quick and easy but once again... you should evaluate this need and solution! Hope it helps!

Comment: Why would you hide special prices in CSS? Those sale prices are usually for a limited time. When the sale ends, you want the prices to go back to normal, not just hide them with CSS. If all you do is hide them, then the customer gets a nice surprise when they check out, and you lose money.

Comment: lol? Really?  so you want your customer to buy the product probably for free?